# How to protect data integrity in IoT network?

Tags: cryptography

The security of IoT devices is very important to protect the data uploaded by IoT devices. Because if an attacker force an IoT device to upload misleading/false data, the analytics and insights generated by IoT system would lead to corrupted information.

Therefore in order to make sure that data uploaded by IoT device is guninue and not fake which is the best technique? or in other words how to ensure that the data sent is sent by an authentic device and not the fake (hacked) device?

for example consider a device that monitor BP of patient and sends info remotely to the doctors device. So that doctor could tell the patient what action to take to avoid heart attack. If attacker clone that BP monitoring device, he could connect to doctor's device to send false BP data to doctor making him to give wrong advice. So in such case how the device at receiving end at doctors side ensures that right data is sent by right device?

Comment: It depends on the devices, the data, the network and so forth. I work in a project were we ensure data integrity by using cabled network and physical access control. It's conceptually easy for users to understand (*Do not leave this door unlocked*), and gives enough security. Other ways may be cryptographic signatures, mutual authentication, or whatever. Remember that an attacker may also be able to manipulate the input of a IOT device, e.g. put a thumb to a termoprobe...I think you should narrow your question down to a more specific set of circumstances that's actually possible to answer.

Comment: @vidarlo can I use [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC)?

Comment: It depends. There's usually not simple answers to as broad questions as this. What are you protecting, whom are you protecting it against, and how valuable is the data?

Comment: @vidarlo i have added example in question kindly see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IoT device needs to have a private key which is unique to this device. In addition, there needs to be a way to associate the corresponding public key with the identity of the device.

The usual way to associate a public key with an identity is with a *certificate*. A certificate is a statement "this public key belongs to this owner, signed, CA". The signer is a *certificate authority*. The server trusts the CA to only generate correct certificates.

You need to arrange to create or inject a private key on the device, have it signed, and send the certificate back to the device. This needs to be done either on the manufacturing chain or later during deployment. If you have a secure element on your device, most SE manufacturers can do this for you.

When the device needs to communicate with the server, it uses a *secure channel* where it uses its private key to authenticate itself. In practice, this means using (D)TLS. Do not roll your own protocol, you would need serious cryptographic expertise. DTLS is the standard for end-to-end communication in IoT.

Don't just sign the data and send it. It wouldn't be protected against replay and wouldn't be encrypted. TLS takes care of both.

In a comment, you mention HMAC. HMAC is not at all suitable for this. Three are two ways to use HMAC here, both wrong. If every device has the same key, then you cannot trust the devices: you have no way to know which device sent some data. It wouldn't even have to be a genuine device: the first time a device gets hacked, the attacker would extract the key. The other way is for every device to have is own key. But since HMAC is symmetric, the server would need to store all the secret keys. If the server ever gets hacked, then all the devices become untrustworthy.

Asymmetric cryptography does not have these problems. If a device is hacked, since every device has its own key, other devices are not affected. If the server gets hacked, you just reinstall it. You should still maintain a list of hacked devices. Depending on your use case, you may have a way to recover, or you may prefer to block the device, or you may keep allowing the device to connect but with reduced trust.

Comment: thanks for nice explanation. So the better option is to have public-private key infrastructure right.

Comment: kindly check your third paragraph, I think 'private key' should be injected in device.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider that an attacker has access to the device, and can *clone* it, all bets are basically off. The attacker can probably read the key from the device, unless extra protection such as secure processors are used - and even then bugs in the design is likely to let a sufficiently skilled attacker retrieve the private keys.

However, if an attacker only has access to listen to the traffic, it's relatively feasible to secure it. HMAC is one way of ensuring that. It ensures integrity and authenticity of the data in question, and is stateless.

But by itself it does [not protect against replay attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39640/can-i-use-a-hmac-for-replay-attack-protection). Replay attacks could very well be a real risk in this scenario.

To reduce attack surface, you should also change keys, e.g. in between patients, ensuring that if Patient A, who had physical access to the device managed to grab keys, those keys are invalid for Patient B.

As blood pressure is health related information, you should consider encryption as well, to ensure secrecy, in addition to ensuring it's authenticity.

You may also consider things such as frequencies and tx power that ensures the attacker has to be physically close to both intercept and transmit. This does not provide security by itself, but it makes it harder both to intercept traffic and inject traffic.